# SMOTE - could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, sampling, resampling, smote

I think I'm missing something in the code below.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE


# Split into training and test sets

# Testing Count Vectorizer

X = df[['Spam']]
y = df['Value']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=40)
X_resample, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X_train, y_train)


sm =  pd.concat([X_resampled, y_resampled], axis=1)
```

as I'm getting the error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> ---> 19 X_resampled, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

Example of data is

```
Spam                                             Value
Your microsoft account was compromised             1
Manchester United lost against PSG                 0
I like cooking                                     0
```

I'd consider to transform both train and test sets to fix the issue which is causing the error, but I don't know how to apply to both. I've tried some examples on google, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: What's the rationale for putting them into a data frame again? The vectorized count is a sparse matrix and it can be really huge on memory if you convert to an array

Comment: @StupidWolf, just for quality check and split into train set, test set and validation set. I would need also for creating feature vector - document term matrix

Comment: so you need to pass the vectorized counts into smote, as the answer below suggest. I don't think it's wise to put them into a data frame after that. You don't need a dataframe for anything downstream

Comment: I did something similar when I oversampled the dataset. So I created some functions and used some already built-in which take as parameter the train_set, test_set, and valid_set after splitting the original dataset into train and test.

Comment: `class_1 = tr_set[tr_set.Label == 1]
class_0 = tr_set[tr_set.Label == 0]

oversample = resample(class_1, 
                       replace=True, 
                       n_samples=len(class_0), 
                       random_state=1)
over_train = pd.concat([class_0, oversample])`. How could I do something similar after using SMOTE? Does it not make sense what I did for oversample/I'd like to do for SMOTE?I'm reading a lot of topics on this, papers, websites...Everyone seems to haven't an idea on how to use re-sampling. I'm learning so I'm following what others suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert text data to numeric before applying SMOTE , like below.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_train.values.ravel())
X_train=vectorizer.transform(X_train.values.ravel())
X_test=vectorizer.transform(X_test.values.ravel())
X_train=X_train.toarray()
X_test=X_test.toarray()
```

and then add your SMOTE code

```
x_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
X_resample, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: what is the shape of X_train?

Comment: I think the count vectorizer is not working as intended. how many data points you have in df ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225916/discussion-between-ravi-and-math).

Comment: thanks Ravi. However this approach, due to the toarray(), seems not working when I try to concatenate x_resampled and y_resampled into a unique dataset: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: add this line before smote calling "
x_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)"

Comment: but this line before SMOTE should still use the not sampled data, should it not? Because I would need something that can consider as train set what I will use after SMOTE

Comment: no all we are doing is converting from NumPy array to pandas dataframe. actually, the error occurred because of trying to use NumPy in pandas concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SMOTENC instead of SMOTE. SMOTENC deals with categorical variables directly.

https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTENC.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTENC

Answer (score 1):

Tokenizing your string data before feeding it into SMOTE is an option. You can use any tokenizer and following torch implementation would be something like:

```
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64)

X, y = [], []

for batch in dataloader:
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    labels = batch['labels']

    X.append(input_ids)
    y.append(labels)

X_tensor = torch.cat(X, dim=0)
y_tensor = torch.cat(y, dim=0)

X = X_tensor.numpy()
y = y_tensor.numpy()

smote = SMOTE(random_state=42, sampling_strategy=0.6)
X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X, y)
```